# rake ts:dd - uninitialized constant Delayed::Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, thinking-sphinx

I am following the instructions on the [thinking sphinx website](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/deltas.html) to setup Delayed Deltas using the Delayed Job plugin.

All appeared to install correct but when I 'rake ts:dd' for the first time, I get this:

```
rake ts:dd --trace
** Invoke ts:dd (first_time)
** Invoke thinking_sphinx:delayed_delta (first_time)
** Invoke thinking_sphinx:app_env (first_time)
** Execute thinking_sphinx:app_env
** Execute thinking_sphinx:delayed_delta
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Delayed::Job
/home/darcbar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/delayed_job-3.0.1/lib/delayed/plugins/clear_locks.rb:9:in `ensure in block (2 levels) in <class:ClearLocks>'
/home/darcbar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/delayed_job-3.0.1/lib/delayed/plugins/clear_locks.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <class:ClearLocks>'
/home/darcbar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/delayed_job-3.0.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:78:in `call'
/home/darcbar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/delayed_job-3.0.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:78:in `block (2 levels) in add'
/home/darcbar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/delayed_job-3.0.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in `call'
/home/darcbar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/delayed_job-3.0.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in `block in initialize'
/home/darcbar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/delayed_job-3.0.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:78:in `call'
/home/darcbar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/delayed_job-3.0.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:78:in `block in add'
/home/darcbar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/delayed_job-3.0.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in `call'
/home/darcbar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/delayed_job-3.0.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in `execute'
/home/darcbar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/delayed_job-3.0.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:38:in `run_callbacks'
/home/darcbar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/delayed_job-3.0.1/lib/delayed/worker.rb:111:in `start'
/home/darcbar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/ts-delayed-delta-1.1.2/lib/thinking_sphinx/deltas/delayed_delta/tasks.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/darcbar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/home/darcbar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/home/darcbar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/home/darcbar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/home/darcbar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/darcbar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/darcbar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/darcbar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/home/darcbar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/home/darcbar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/home/darcbar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/darcbar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/darcbar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/darcbar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/home/darcbar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/home/darcbar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/darcbar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/home/darcbar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/home/darcbar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/darcbar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/home/darcbar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/home/darcbar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/darcbar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/home/darcbar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/darcbar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/home/darcbar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => ts:dd => thinking_sphinx:delayed_delta
```

I have installed:

```
Sphinx 0.9.9
thinking_sphinx 2.0.10
ts-delayed-delta 1.1.2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With delayed job 3 you need to install one of the backend gems, for example `delayed_job_active_record` for the activerecord backend.